# How to pass two functions to onClick event in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to pass two functions to `onClick` event which is `handleSubmit` and `handleDelete` to the `HomePage.js` from the `HomeItem.js`

Here is my Error:
**`No duplicate props allowed react/jsx-no-duplicate-props.`**

Here is my HomePage.js:

```
 const HomePage = props => {
  const tvshow = props.item;
  let res;

  if (tvshow.length > 0) {
    res = tvshow.map(res=> (
      <Content item={res} onClick={props.onClick}/>
    ));
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Container>
        <Row>{res}</Row>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
};

export default HomePage;
```

Here is my HomeItem.js:

```
const HomeItem = props => {
  function handleSubmit() {
    props.onClick({
      name: props.item.name,
      id: props.item.id
    });
  }

  function handleName() {
    props.onClick({
      name: props.item.name
    });
  }

<Button onClick={handleSubmit}></Button>
<Button onClick={handleName}></Button>
```

Here is my App.js:

```
handleSubmit(newFavorite) {}
handleName(newFavorite) {}

render() {
  <Route
    exact
    path="/"
    render={() => (
      <HomePage
        item={this.state.SaveFavorite}
        onClick={this.handleSubmit}
        onClick={this.handleName}
      />
    )}
  />
}
```

So my question is how to put 2 onClick function to the Hompage.js

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? 2 different functionalities for the button? or when you click a button you want to run one function and then a second one?

Comment: why 2 functions for one `onClick`? why not, 2 separate ones? like `onSubmitClick` and `onNameClick`?

Answer (score 5):

How about this:

```
<HomePage
        item={this.state.SaveFavorite}
        onClick={(favorite)=>{
            this.handleSubmit(favorite);
            this.handleName(favorite);
            }
        }
        />
```

This assumes your goal is to call both functions one at a time. If they should be called in different situations give one function a different name, eg `onSubmit` or `onNameChange`.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
<HomePage
     item={this.state.SaveFavorite}
     onClick={(newFavorite) => this.handleSubmit(newFavorite);this.handleName(newFavorite)}
 />
```

Comment: what if first one is asynchronous ..i want the second one to be executed only after the first one gets successfully completed

Answer (score 0):

you can pass multiple functions to events in react, let say changeEvent, to do follow those steps.

1- create your function two or the number of function you like.

2- create an object that contains those functions

3- pass the object as a props to where it would be consumed

4- choose the correspondant function to each form or whatever you need.

here is an example, this sample is with typescript.

```
  const onChangeFunctions = {
    onChangeForm1: handleChangeForm1,
    onChangeForm2: handleChangeForm2,
};

   <MainForm
      onChange={onChangeFunctions} // here is your function
      datas={yourData}
      otherProps={otherProps}
    />
```

Now you use the fucntion on the child components

```
interface PropsFrom {
  model1: Model1;
  model2: Model2;
  onChange: any;
}

export default function ProductForm(props: PropsForm) {
 return (
  <Container maxWidth="lg">
    <Grid item md={6}>
      <FormOne
        model={props.model1} // the model that bind your form
        onChange={props.onChange.onChangeForm1} // here you can use your first function
      />
    </Grid>

   <Grid item md={6}>
      <FormTwo
        model={props.model2} // the model that bind your form
        onChange={props.onChange.onChangeForm2} // here you can use your second function
        />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  </Container>
```

for javascript just pass the functions as props and delete the interface from the child components.