# How to add two functions passed as props to an onChange event in React and Material UI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, onchange, react-props

I want to add two functions passed in as props to an onChange event. `handleInput` is a function that sets the value when changed, and `validate` is a function that validates the input.

I've been reading through these posts but their answers are not working: [How to pass two functions to onClick event in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53084453/how-to-pass-two-functions-to-onclick-event-in-react/53084612) and [call two functions within onchange event in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54032379/call-two-functions-within-onchange-event-in-react)

```
const FormFields = (props) => {

   const { values, handleInput, validate } =
    props;

   // Created a function to return two functions passed as props.
   const handleOnChange = (event) => {
      return {
         handleInput,
         validate,
      };
   };

   return (
      <TextField
          name="selection"
          label="Select"
          value={values}
          onChange={handleOnChange} // <- Function with two functions collapsed.
      />
   )
}
```

Comment: Do you need to call both functions on onChange event?

Comment: @Prana I could prefer having both on the onChange. event Is it not possible?

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

call those functions inside handle OnChange instead of returning them

```
   const handleOnChange = (event) => {
      handleInput(event)
      validate(event)
   };
```

Comment: Adding "event" in those two parameters worked like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add an anynoymous function that calls the other funcitons like:

```
<TextField
          name="selection"
          label="Select"
          value={values}
          onChange={()=> {functionOne(); functionTwo()}} // <- Function with two functions collapsed.
      />
```